# Object Oriented, Controller issues, Beginner Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript and coding in general.
I have a controller.js that i cant touch and have to build the program around.

```
// Add teams 
bra = the2016OlympicMens7s.addTeam("Brazil", "BRA", "Southern", 11, "A");
fij = the2016OlympicMens7s.addTeam("Fiji", "FIJ", "Southern", 1, "A");
// Add the Pool Matches
poolA = the2016OlympicMens7s.poolA;
pool.addMatch(bra, fij);
```

I've setup everything else except for the matches themselves, I can see the each team object stored inside an array, and can see each match but i cant figure out how to add the team object using the code (eg fij) to the match.

```
//Pool.js
pool.prototype.addMatch = function (aMatch) {
    "use strict";
     var newMatch = new Match(aMatch);
     this.allMyMatches.push(newMatch);
};

//Match.js
var Match = function (a, b) {
    this.teamA = a
    this.teamB = b
};
```

I don't understand what (bra, fij) are since they are not strings but they also haven't been defined as a variable. Hopefully this make some sense to someone.

Comment: Do you mean `poolA.addMatch` in the last line of the first code block ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Javascript is a loosely typed language: This means the type of a variable is coerced by the interpreter.
2. Not using a var keyword a variable gets the global scope.

   In javascript variables are defined as:

   ```
   var a = "1"; // String with value 1
   var b = 10; // Number with value 10
   var c = 1 + "10"; //String with value 110
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to declare a variable before using it in java script.

Comment: Actually it's useful often for scoping issues. Also you should always use `var` so it doesn't accidentally create a global.

Comment: Thanks, this should be taken into consideration.